# Offsetting position of a View in a AppWidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I am creating an AppWidget that allows users to skin the widget and download from a list of widgets online.  I would like to allow skinners to offset the position of the icons vertically.

I initally tried calling offsetTopAndBottom on the LinearLayout that holds the icons, this is not allowed as its not supported with RemoteViews.

I then had an idea of using 2 Views inside a LinearLayout (on top and below the icon Layout) to "squash" the icons towards the bottom (if the height of the top layout was set to > 0).

When I tried to set the height of these views: -

```
 views.setInt(R.id.iconMarginTop, "setMinimumHeight", offset);
```

it also complained that it wasn't supported with RemoteViews

Any ideas what I could do to acheive this offset?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this can be done.  The best thing I can think of is to have multiple layouts with the view at different positions.  This might not suit every situations though